# Self Service API - There is not enough adults to accompany infants and children

Tags: amadeus

I'm testing out flight-create-order API and tried to create an order with 01 Adult and 01 Child.

But alas I'm getting the below cryptic error. Please kindly help me to debug this issue.

Works fine when only adults are selected. Once i add either a child or held_infant, this error or TOO_OLD error get returned.

```
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [status] => 400
                [code] => 4926
                [title] => INVALID DATA RECEIVED
                [detail] => There is not enough adults to accompany infants and children
            )

    )
```

The JSON payload I'm posting is mentioned below.

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "flight-order",
    "flightOffers": [
        {
            "type": "flight-offer",
            "id": "1",
            "source": "GDS",
            "instantTicketingRequired": false,
            "nonHomogeneous": false,
            "oneWay": false,
            "lastTicketingDate": "2023-12-27",
            "lastTicketingDateTime": "2023-12-27",
            "numberOfBookableSeats": 9,
            "itineraries": [
                {
                    "duration": "PT3H40M",
                    "segments": [
                        {
                            "departure": {
                                "iataCode": "CMB",
                                "at": "2023-12-27T00:30:00"
                            },
                            "arrival": {
                                "iataCode": "DEL",
                                "terminal": "3",
                                "at": "2023-12-27T04:10:00"
                            },
                            "carrierCode": "UL",
                            "number": "191",
                            "aircraft": {
                                "code": "320"
                            },
                            "operating": {
                                "carrierCode": "UL"
                            },
                            "duration": "PT3H40M",
                            "id": "17",
                            "numberOfStops": 0,
                            "blacklistedInEU": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "duration": "PT3H40M",
                    "segments": [
                        {
                            "departure": {
                                "iataCode": "DEL",
                                "terminal": "3",
                                "at": "2024-01-27T05:10:00"
                            },
                            "arrival": {
                                "iataCode": "CMB",
                                "at": "2024-01-27T08:50:00"
                            },
                            "carrierCode": "UL",
                            "number": "192",
                            "aircraft": {
                                "code": "32A"
                            },
                            "operating": {
                                "carrierCode": "UL"
                            },
                            "duration": "PT3H40M",
                            "id": "41",
                            "numberOfStops": 0,
                            "blacklistedInEU": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "price": {
                "currency": "LKR",
                "total": "261138.00",
                "base": "116200.00",
                "fees": [
                    {
                        "amount": "0.00",
                        "type": "SUPPLIER"
                    },
                    {
                        "amount": "0.00",
                        "type": "TICKETING"
                    }
                ],
                "grandTotal": "261138.00"
            },
            "pricingOptions": {
                "fareType": [
                    "PUBLISHED"
                ],
                "includedCheckedBagsOnly": false
            },
            "validatingAirlineCodes": [
                "UL"
            ],
            "travelerPricings": [
                {
                    "travelerId": "1",
                    "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                    "travelerType": "ADULT",
                    "price": {
                        "currency": "LKR",
                        "total": "138869.00",
                        "base": "66400.00"
                    },
                    "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                        {
                            "segmentId": "17",
                            "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                            "fareBasis": "NE1MLK",
                            "class": "N",
                            "includedCheckedBags": {
                                "weight": 30,
                                "weightUnit": "KG"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "segmentId": "41",
                            "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                            "fareBasis": "NE1MLK",
                            "class": "N",
                            "includedCheckedBags": {
                                "weight": 30,
                                "weightUnit": "KG"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "travelerId": "2",
                    "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                    "travelerType": "CHILD",
                    "price": {
                        "currency": "LKR",
                        "total": "122269.00",
                        "base": "49800.00"
                    },
                    "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                        {
                            "segmentId": "17",
                            "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                            "fareBasis": "NE1MLKCH25",
                            "class": "N"
                        },
                        {
                            "segmentId": "41",
                            "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                            "fareBasis": "NE1MLKCH25",
                            "class": "N"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "travelers": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": {
                "firstName": "Jhon",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            "dateOfBirth": "2020-10-10",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "documents": [
                {
                    "documentType": "PASSPORT",
                    "number": "N8144555",
                    "holder": true,
                    "nationality": "LK",
                    "expiryDate": "2025-02-24",
                    "issuanceCountry": "LK"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": {
                "firstName": "Jhon",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            "dateOfBirth": "2020-10-10",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "documents": [
                {
                    "documentType": "PASSPORT",
                    "number": "N8144555",
                    "holder": true,
                    "nationality": "LK",
                    "expiryDate": "2025-02-24",
                    "issuanceCountry": "LK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "contacts": [
        {
            "phones": [
                {
                    "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                    "countryCallingCode": "94",
                    "number": "071 473 7212"
                }
            ],
            "emailAddress": "jhondoe@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive this error message, because you have indeed no adult defined in the API request. You have two travelers with `"dateOfBirth": "2020-10-10"`. If you change the date of birth of one travelers to be an adult, you won't receive this error anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anna dear, much obliged